# identifiy outliers in 2 variable dataset in R

Tags: r, variables, double, identity, outliers

I have a dataset of 2 variables. I want to check for outliers. [image]

There is at least one as you can see. But may R code returns zero is there.

```
data1 <- read.csv("new_go.csv",header = TRUE)
plot(data1$logTENmb, data1$logTENS)
dev.off()
plot.new()
outliers <- identify(data1$logmb, data1$logcopy)
outliers
```

Comment: why don't you use `identify(data1$logTENmb, data1$logTENS)` ?

Comment: oh thanks. Ya that should do it

Comment: This approach seems non-scaleable.